# PHP, Nginx: Call {name}.php when url is sitename.com/{name}

Tags: php, nginx

Use `nginx` server.

What and how should be done when the URL is `sitename.com/test` and there is   a call to test.php

For example:

project structure

```
public_html
|
+-somedir1
| |
| +-somefiles....
+-somdir2
|
+-login.php
+-info.php
+-something.php
......
```

when the url is  `sitename.com/login`... call `login.php`,  `sitename.com/info` call `info.php` etc.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    root /home/prod/frontend;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name ui;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ui.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ui.error.log;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

also i try

```
location / {
            try_files $uri.php $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location / {
            index $uri.php
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the myriad of php nginx tutorials? If so, show us the config that doesn't work.

Comment: ofc i read it... but i can find the way